# confusion about accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Somehow, I was under impression that `accepts_nested_attributes_for` will let me populate child object through parent:

```
person.update_attributes person_hash
```

but in practice I ended up doing this:

```
person.address.update_attributes person_hash[:address]
person_hash.delete :address
person.update_attributes person_hash
```

Now, http://guides.rubyonrails.org mentions accepts_nested_attributes_for only indirectly and API documentation for this method is also quite cryptic.

1) Could someone show basic use-case for accepts_nested_attributes_for? I mean, I understand how it's declared, I'm confused about the difference it makes.

2) Is the way I populate nested object the 'right' one in rails, or there's something more 'elegant'?

Thanks!

**update**
Model, for clarity

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

**update2**, for j.
Form declaration goes like this

```
<% fields_for "people", person, :index => person.id do |person_form| %>
  ... 
  <% person_form.fields_for person.address do |address_form| %>
    <%= address_form.text_field :street %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

But it gives me html names like `people[66][address][street]` and not `people[66][address_attributes][street]`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `form_for :people` instead of `fields_for`?

Comment: @j. nope, I have one form declaration for several 'person' records. And overall, somewhere on http://guides.rubyonrails.org it was said that fields_for is same as form_for for all practical purposes, only doesn't create <form> element.

Comment: I have _<% form_tag("url_here", :method => "post", :id => "edit_tips_form") do %>_ encompassing it all.

Comment: And I tried _<% form_for :person do |person_form| %>_ instead, same stuff :(   But at least, now I understand how it's supposed to work, thanks :)

Comment: I've updated my answer. Unfortunately I don't know why the `params` are going that way :/

Answer (score 3):

With `accepts_nested_attributes_for` you can do the following:

```
# example from railsapi.com
# view
<% form_for @person, :url => { :action => "create" } do |person_form| %>
   Name: <%= person_form.text_field :name %>
   ...
   <% person_form.fields_for :address do |address_fields| %>
     Street  : <%= address_fields.text_field :street %>
     Zip code: <%= address_fields.text_field :zip_code %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

With this, your parameters will look like

```
params = { 
   :person => { 
      :name => 'Jack',
      :address_attributes => { :street => 'Street', :zip_code => '11111' } 
   }
}
```

and you're able to create a person and the related address just using

```
@person = Person.create(params)
```

For more information, [`railsapi.com`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). I hope it helps.

**Edit**

I have no idea why your params look like this :/
But using

```
#person.address.update_attributes person_hash.delete(:address) OR
person.address.update_attributes person_hash[:address]
person_hash.delete :address

person.update_attributes person_hash
```

is not *wrong*. Just could be done with more *elegant* code, as you said.

Comment: Actually, I declare form in the same way, but I get parameter names in style "people[66][address][street]" and not "people[66][address_attributes][street]"